# Looking for HTTP debugging proxy for Mac similar to Fiddler on Windows

Tags: macos, mac, http, web-development, sniffing

In previous jobs when I've worked on a Windows machine, I've used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for viewing HTTP transactions and debugging.

I'm specifically looking to monitor the HTTP transactions for an ajax site I'm working on to verify that the site is doing what I expect. Rewriting HTTP (as provided by Fiddler) is a nice-to-have, but not essential.

Can anybody recommend something similar for use on a Mac?

Comment: This has been closed, but still exists, so needs to have added: Fiddler is now in alpha for the mac os.

Comment: i don't know why this would be closed?  it has 113 upvotes.  it's not like this was an ask on stack overflow.

Comment: Read the rationale directly above these comments -- "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic"

Comment: Fireup Fiddler on nearby Windows machine and configure your MAC to proxy over Windows machine and voila! everything on your MAC will be seen on Windows :)

Comment: FYI, for those who got really excited reading @boomhauer 's comment: Fiddler for OSX is *still* in Alpha, having last been touched in July 2013, it requires the Mono framework (so it's basically just a wrapper for the Windows version, not actually re-factored for Cocoa), and the release has the note: "Mac Note: The WinForms framework on Mac is almost unusably buggy. Your best bet is to run Fiddler inside a Linux or Windows Virtual Machine and point the Mac's proxy settings at that."

Comment: You can use Owasp Zap to do this - it can be inserted as a browser based proxy, or system wide proxy, and intercepts ALL calls to all websites (http and https), and allows you to modify and log all requests. It even generates dynamic SSL certs on the fly for all websites. Here's a quick [tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXoJQz6uIQ0), and [here's a quick step by step of the process too](http://havrl.blogspot.ca/2015/03/inspecting-http-traffic-using-owasp-zed.html). It's intended to be used for penetration testing, but works great for this case as well.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I found [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). It's much closer to the functionality of Fiddler. It's not free, but it may be worth the price.

Comment: Just curious: did anyone here ever use it?

Comment: I used it for an hour or two after I found it. The trial version has some nag screens and a 30 minute restriction, but I don't think those are unreasonable. I was looking for specific headers in the HTTP response and I was able to see these easily.

Comment: The nice thing about Charles is that it is available for both OSX and Windows so if you go back and forth frequently it's a nice common tool.

Comment: An important functionality that charles (and fiddler and maybe webscarab) provide is the ability to intercept and modify requests, including https decryption.

Comment: I use Charles to decrypt Instagram, Facebook and other mobile apps https requests. Just point iPhone Proxy to Charles and I'm able see how they send data and what data they send!

Comment: I am not able to see decompressed response for my requests. Is there a way to set charles to automatically decompress and show the result

Comment: @Harsh, in my experience, Charles does automatically decompress the response (if you're looking at the text or html view) if it is compressed in someway for the browser. (E.g., GZip compression.) If you're talking about HTTPS issues, though, (e.g., encryption), you will need to install the Charles Proxy certificate, which will decrypt those and make them human-readable. If that does not address your issue, please consider opening a question here on a Stack Exchange site, or opening a ticket with Charles Proxy. (Note: I am not employed by Charles Proxy, but I am a happy user of their software.)

Comment: Oh, and to address the really old question of "anyone here ever use it?", I use it pretty frequently. Extremely useful for web debugging, and, not to promote such behaviour, but if you want to try your hand at online game exploitation, it is pretty useful for that as well ;-)

Answer (score 136):

Use Chrome and navigate to chrome://net-internals/

It allows detailed analysis and dumps.

Comment: Nice. Any idea when that was added to chrome?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I used to work with Fiddler on Windows, but moving to a Mac I stumbled over net-internals while looking for hidden chrome features.

Comment: this tool seems "neat" but how can you see the entire request payload (i.e. GET request headers?)

Comment: AFAIK, this does not offer a way to modify the data in transit such as Fiddler does with FiddlerScript, AutoResponder, and breakpoints. Good tool but for different purposes.

Comment: @Jaj: that info is already present in the network tab of DevTools

Comment: this tool only seems to capture chrome traffic. Is there any way to use this tool to capture http traffic from/to a a particular process?

Comment: can this be used to debug traffic from iPhone simulator

Answer (score 40):

I've used [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) for intercepting HTTP traffic. It's a great tool and you can use it for debugging mobile devices as well or any operating system for that matter.

Comment: LOOVE THIS!  Incidentally, for all the script kiddies, in case you write code in something other than JS sitting in the browser, this thing is THE ticket.

Comment: NB: Requires Xcode 11.1

Comment: is that safe to use? downloading a lot of things when i type the install command. i wonder why

Answer (score 28):

My favorite mac app for monitoring traffic is [HTTPScoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/), I detail that as well as using tcpdump from the commandline in [this post I blogged last year](http://naleid.com/blog/2008/04/03/monitoring-http-traffic-to-debug-your-grails-application/).

Comment: If you happen to know Wireshark (or the less powerful Cocoa Packet Analyzer): can you compare HTTPScoop to that?

Comment: It's quite a bit simpler, but much easier to use than wireshark IMO.  Very easy to fire up and monitor http traffic with, but less adept at monitoring other kinds of traffic.  I'm not familiar with cocoa packet analyzer.

Comment: Cocoa Packet Analyzer is quite simple too. However, I never figured out how to filter some specific port or server IP address, and then see *both* the request and reply... That's easily done in Wireshark. (Just type `smtp` as display filter to see all traffic that uses the SMTP protocol. Or `tcp.port == 25` to get all traffic to port 25, *and* its responses. Or `http and ip.addr == xxx` to get all HTTP traffic to and from some server.)

Comment: httpscoop looked promising, unfortunately it seems to be abandoned and I was unable to capture localhost traffic on 10.9.2. The last release dates back to 2009 and the website touts ans upcoming v2.0 which doesn't seem to be forthcoming :/

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: Sorry, this app is a piece of trash for two reason. It has like 3 buttons and the author still needs to provide a video of how to use it. Let's not forget to mention that when you press scoop and refresh the browser page absolutely nothing shows up!

Comment: I tried to use this app, it's horrible compared with fiddler. I want to capture all traffic and all ports all interfaces not port 80 on localhost. I tried to add the ports I wanted thru preferences (with scoop off). This did not help me as the things I wanted to monitor were on two different interfaces e.g lo / en0

Comment: Link to blog not working :(

Answer (score 19):

Not what you asked, but in Firefox the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/3829) add-on is all I need if I want to edit and re-play requests, including changing the URL and the HTTP method.

[image: Live HTTP Headers]

In Firebug, the [Network Monitoring](http://getfirebug.com/network) shows all requests and responses. Likewise, in Safari the [Resources pane](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/) of the built-in Web Inspector covers most of my needs as well. (Enable the Web Inspector through the preferences: *Show Develop menu in menu bar*.) Chrome and Firefox have similar tools.

When things get more complicated, I fire up my [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) packet sniffer. However, unlike Fiddler, Wireshark does not let you *change* the data, and does not support things like auto responders, like Fiddler apparently does.

For Wireshark, see [Hyper Text Transfer Protocol (HTTP)](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Hyper_Text_Transfer_Protocol) for some generic HTTP capturing information, and [HTTP Packet Capturing to debug Apache](http://www.askapache.com/software/sniff-http-to-debug-apache-htaccess-and-httpdconf.html), for some example *display* filters. (You may want to set the *capture* filter to "`port 80`", to show all requests *to* that port, and responses *from* that port. Or, to limit to some server, use *capture* filter "`port 80 and host www.google.com`".) Like:

```
# Show only 404: page not found
http.response.code == 404

# Show only certain HTTP methods
http.request.method == "POST" || http.request.method == "PUT"

# Show only javascript
http.content_type contains "javascript"
```

Note that Wireshark can decompress gzip or deflate encoded (compressed) things on the fly for you. That makes things much easier to read as most web servers will compress the data they send to a browser.

(As for auto responders: the excellent [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/about) has a short video on how to use it to debug Ajax requests. If you don't know JS Bin, then first view the introduction video.)

Comment: +1 for Firebug -- I love their network monitoring tool

Comment: I tried it but I couldn't make a new request to a different url (in the same domain) and couldn't find how (from a GET to a POST for example).

Comment: @Purefan, without more detail we cannot help; it works for me, see the screenshot I just added. You may have run into https://www.mozdev.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25831

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Charles (already mentioned), I also like the **[HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/)** add-on for Mozilla Firefox.  Like Charles, you can use it on both Mac and Windows.  It's lighter-weight than Charles because it lives in the browser, useful for quick troubleshooting.  Here's some information from the HttpFox page:

> HttpFox monitors and analyzes all incoming and outgoing HTTP traffic
>   between the browser and the web servers.
>
> It aims to bring the functionality known from tools like HttpWatch or
>   IEInspector to the Firefox browser.
>
> Information available per request includes:
>
> - Request and response headers
> - Sent and received cookies
> - Querystring parameters
> - POST parameters
> - Response body

And, a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of HttpFox add-on for Mozilla Firefox]

Comment: This is not compatible with the newer versions of Firefox (Firedox 57 and Firedex Deveolper Edition 57)

Answer (score 6):

Not a proxy, but it does help in debugging HTTP:

- [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Simply start a scan on the interface you're going to have the HTTP traffic on, execute the traffic and then stop scanning and type "HTTP" as the filter string. You will then be able to inspect all the packets of the HTTP conversation. With the Packet Detail view open you can open the HTTP section and it will stay open between packets.

It's a great tool to have and it doesn't require you to change the browser proxy. On the other hand it cannot help with HTTPS traffic since that's encrypted. (Although it [can decrypt SSL connections that use RSA](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL))

Comment: Just an update: Wireshark is pain on OS X. It requires X11, which is no longer included in OS X, so you end up using some 200MB of disk all together.

Comment: Just an update on @MarkoBonaci update, Wireshark 2.x now runs great on OSX ditched the need for X11.

Comment: @MarkoBonaci - you should just install with qt instead.

Answer (score 5):

I'm late but - I use [Paros Proxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/). It's in Java, so, cross-platform. Though if you would prefer for it to be packaged as an app, there's one [here](http://research.corsaire.com/tools/) at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget Burp Suite. They have a free version. It's cross platform. http://portswigger.net/burp/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the free [GlimmerBlocker](http://glimmerblocker.org/) can do part of the trick.

Of course it can block all kind of content, and [transform](http://glimmerblocker.org/wiki/Transform2) responses before the browser receives them. But it can in fact [modify both requests and responses](http://glimmerblocker.org/wiki/Flow). And though not true debugging, it also offers logging. So, it might suit [basic needs](http://glimmerblocker.org/wiki/ObjectReference):

> There are 4 types of scripts running inside GlimmerBlocker, and some objects are only defined for some of the script types:
>
> - global proxy: this sets the global proxy settings, and can test for e.g. location name, AirPort network.
> - request modification: this can change the requested URL, send back a redirect response to the browser, or send text/html back to the browser.
> - keyword expansion. [Safari-only, AvB]
> - transform: modify the response received by the web-server before it is sent back to Safari [or any browser that is set up to use the proxy provided by GlimmerBlocker, AvB].

(One can also use it to include various Greasemonkey scripts in the received response, without using a Greasemonkey add-on, like [to block Flash](https://superuser.com/questions/89808/whats-the-best-flash-blocker-for-the-chrome-browser-on-a-mac/92145#92145) without installing any add-on.)

Comment: GlimmerBlocker is an interesting tool, but different than what I'm looking for. I've re-edited the original description to remove the rewrite examples and clarify that I'm merely looking to monitor the traffic and not transform it.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily configure [Fiddler for Mac](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForMac) using Parallels as per instructions on their site.

The only caveat is that you have to manually configure your Network settings to point to the IP address of the VM but not really that big of a deal.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "easily" - it requires buying and installing a vm server and an entirely different operating system.

Comment: I have 5 entries in this tooltip and only one of them is IPv4 format. Which one should I pick? :)

Comment: You can use free virtualization software such as Oracle's [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) along with a VM from [modern.ie](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/) if you want to run a Windows OS (after 90 days it needs to be reset) -- not too tall of an order for someone with the skills needed to run an advanced web debug proxy

Comment: If this question was open - someone should mention Fiddler for Mac - http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler using Mono framework...

Comment: And it is not working for me in macOS

Answer (score 1):

jMeter might also be helpful; it's designed for testing load performance on web servers, but it might still do what you need.  jMeter is written in Java, so you can download a .jar file that will run on Mac, Windows, or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

[Cocoa Packet Analyzer](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/) is very helpful.

Comment: How is it helpful? A cliffs notes version of that would be hugely helpful

Comment: cocoa packet analyzer was able to successfuly capture HTTP trafic but it doesn't do request/response reconstruction :(

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with app traffic or third-party API integrations that go over the public internet, you should try Runscope (of which, full disclosure, I am a co-founder). It captures HTTP requests to any URL, gives you a nice stream view for debugging and makes it easy to share individual requests with others.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [APIKitchen](http://apikitchen.com). It helps you in debugging and testing HTTP APIs and any requests in general. It also has an offline version for testing in your internal networks. No installation necessary.