# Clear Safari HTML5 local storage on Windows

Tags: windows, safari, html5, local-storage

I am trying to the clear the HTML5 local storage for Safari on a Windows system. I had a look at this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/236558/how-to-clear-all-html5-local-storage-from-safari) but I can only find answers tailored to macs. Does anyone know how?

Comment: People actually use Safari on Windows? :/

Comment: yes...can it be done?

Comment: New versions of Safari support clearing this; see the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The physical folder should be in `%APPDATA%\Apple\Safari` or some variant (somebody said it might be `Apple Computer` but I doubt it).

At that point it's the same as the post you linked to. Find the Local Storage folder (or possibly file) and empty it.